# How to apply ng-required in MultiSelect?

Tags: angularjs, multi-select

I am using searchable-multiselect in angular js, ng-required=true is not working in multiselect.How to apply ng-required in MultiSelect ?

```
<searchable-multiselect display-attr="name"  selected-items="users.user" all-items="allusers" ng-required=true
```

add-item="add(item,user)" remove-item="remove(item,user)"  ng-model="dropdownValues">

Answer (score 0):

You can only apply `ng-required` onto directives that require `ng-model`.  Looking into the `searchable-multiselect` directive, it doesn't require `ng-model` nor does it have any `required` configuration.

The easiest way to do form validity on this would be to add a hidden input that contains something you can do validity on.   In this case you can use the model object that you're storing the data on.  In the example below, we're checking the length of the selected items and requiring there be a minimum of 1 entry.

```
<input 
    style="display: none;" 
    type="number"
    ng-model="dropdownValues.length" 
    ng-required="true" 
    min="1" />
```

Working Plunkr: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/gkxUvPVK0NkdOewj

Answer (score -1):

Use the following :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div 
   multi-select
   input-model="batch_timing.days"
   output-model="resultData"
   button-label="acronym"
   item-label="acronym symbol name"
   tick-property="ticked"
   helper-elements="all none reset"
   required name="days">
</div>
<button ng-click="validation()">submit</button>
```

```js
$scope.resultData = [];

$scope.validation = function () {
  if($scope.resultData === null || $scope.resultData == '') {
    return false; // not validated
  } else {
    return true; // validated
  }
}
```